# I tried to replace all 0 values with profit or loss Using Function

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

```
def p_l(cols):
    cost_price = cols[0]
    selling_price = cols[1]
    
    if np.zeros('profit_or_loss'):
    
        if(cost_price<selling_price):
            return 'profit'
    
        else:
            return 'loss'
    else:
        return profit_or_loss


df['profit_or_loss']=df[['cost_price','selling_price']].apply(p_l,axis=1)
```

> TypeError: ("'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer",
> 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Hey there.  Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide sample input along with your explanation and expected output to improve your chances of getting a good response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `np.zeros('profit_or_loss')` - np.zeros is used to create an array of zeros - here you are trying to see if profit_or_loss is zero or not

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the column 'profit_or_loss' is initialize to zero.

The goal is to create a function that computes profit or loss (and replaces the zeros).

```
# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'cost_price': [1, 3, 6, 8, 9],
                   'sell_price': [2, 4, 5, 7, 9],
                   'profit_or_loss': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  }).assign(change = lambda x: x['sell_price'] - x['cost_price'])

def profit_loss(sell, cost):
    return (sell >= cost).map({True: 'profit', False: 'loss'})

# compute P&L
df['profit_or_loss'] = profit_loss(df['sell_price'], df['cost_price'])

df
```

With large data frames, it will be relatively slow to use `.apply(..., axis=1)`.  It's much faster to define functions that operate on both scalars and vectors/series.  (Not always possible, though.)